# Debugging into multiple projects

Tags: .net, debugging, dll, project

I am working with `.NET 4`.
I have multiple projects in the solution.
I am using a dll created by one project as a reference inside another project.
But, while debugging the main project, how can I enter debugging into the referenced dll? I wanted to debug into the referenced dll also.

Comment: Is F11 (Step Into) not working? Then maybe you do not have proper build configuration (DEBUG) set. Or if you reference the dll from file (not project) then you should check if you have corresponding .pdb file to the referenced dll.

Comment: Nope. It is not working. It is treating it as dll only.

Comment: What about the pdb file? Is it in bin folder of master application that references the dll?

Comment: Nope it is in the Debug folder inside bin of project which had created the dll

Comment: Then copy it to the bin folder of master application. Dll should correspond to the pdb so please check that dll in bin folder of master application is the same as dll in bin/Debug folder of dll-project.